# Pygame Game Freezing on load

Tags: python, pygame

I'm creating a game in pygame and I want different "States" for the game, so when the player_y is smaller than 10 the background changes and the enemys on the screen change, but whenever i try and launch the game, it freezes up and doesn't load, but when I didn't have the "State" change code in, it launched fine.

My game variables:

```
black    = (   0,   0,   0)
white    = ( 255, 255, 255)
red      = ( 255,   0,   0)
background_image = pygame.image.load("background.png")
player_y = 20
y_speed = 0
obj_speed = 0.5
sky = 0
player_x = 50
```

My "State Change Code":

```
while sky == 0:
    screen.blit(pygame.image.load("background.png"), [0,0])
    all_sprites_list.draw(screen)
    if player_y < 10:
        sky == 1
while sky == 1:
    player_y = 390
    screen.blit(pygame.image.load("sky.png"), [0,0])
    player_list.draw(screen)
    wof_list.draw(screen)
```

EDIT: http://pastebin.com/5Vj6vjBJ here is a pastebin link to the full code.

Comment: Why did you delete your http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40265608/removing-all-non-letter-characters-from-a-string-in-java-and-adding-them-to-an-a question? I could provide an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the while loop is never being broken. While it is looping, nothing outside of the loop can happen, so the player y variable can't be changed and thus the sky variable never becomes 1. This is basically an infinite loop.
I think that this could be fixed by replacing the two "while"s with "if"s.
I hope that this is more helpful than my previous answer.

P.S. Then put the "player_y = 390" into the "if player_y < 10" statement, below "sky =1", so that it only happens when the background is changed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your `if player_y < 10:` statement, you are not actually changing the value of `sky` but simply doing an equality check with `sky == 1`. Fix it as follows:

```
if sky == 0:
    screen.blit(pygame.image.load("background.png"), [0,0])
    all_sprites_list.draw(screen)
    if player_y < 10:
        sky = 1
if sky == 1:
    player_y = 390
    screen.blit(pygame.image.load("sky.png"), [0,0])
    player_list.draw(screen)
    wof_list.draw(screen)
```

Comment: Nope, it still freezes on startup with no error message in the console. Thanks for your help though

Comment: @DarudeOfDeath, Can you please your full code [here](http://pastebin.com/) and share link here so that I can debug your problem? Thanks